# how can i open discord server invite with intent based URI?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, discord

I want an intent to open discord server in android.

I know how to do it for twitter, tried like this but does not work

```
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=username")));
} catch (Exception e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/username")));
}
```

Comment: Please post log what is problem error it shows

Comment: when I do this- startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("discord://invite/uWrSv3"))); nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found our by testing different things that If you have discord installed you don't explicitly need to specify anything, I did it as follows

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://discord.gg/invitecode")))
```